# Pass credentials to iframe

Tags: html, http, iframe, xmlhttprequest, credentials

I have a number of Axis cameras and I am trying to create a page that has a list of the cameras that then loads the camera in an iframe when you click on them.

Changing the `src` of an `iframe` to the ip of the camera is easy with some JS, but then each camera is needing to log in with **BASIC authentication**.
I don't want each user to have to log in to each camera each time they load the page, and I dont have control over the camera logins.

I have tried to send an `http request` with the credentials in my page first (and got a `200` response) and then loaded the `iframe` but it still prompts for login when I load the camera page in the iframe.

Previously this could be done with `http://user:pass@host/` but that has now been deprecated in chrome.
Anyone have any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? There is an issue where Chrome 59 and later is not allowing passwords or credentials embedding in URLs for security reasons. But, I haven't found any mention of a good alternative yet. https://medium.com/@lmakarov/say-goodbye-to-urls-with-embedded-credentials-b051f6c7b6a3